# Is Azure Automation DSC at all suitable for configuring client machines (not servers)?

Tags: azure, automation, dsc

I am trying to create a DSC configuration for a developer workstation and facing difficulties.

A developer machine has a well defined owner - the developer who is going to get it. Some configurations tightly coupled to the owner account:

1. It should be added to the Sql Server as a login account in sysadmin role.
2. Visual Studio extensions that I want every developer to have must be installed from a session started by the owner account (not the SYSTEM account used to apply the DSC configurations)
3. The TFS workspaces must be associated with the owner account.

It is unclear to me how Azure Automation DSC can allow for such coupling. Sometimes just the account name is needed (to configure Sql Server), but sometimes the resource must be run as the owner, i.e. the owner credentials are needed. Unless there is a way for a DSC resource to run as the workstation owner without knowing owner's credentials.

In short, it seems to me that Azure Automation DSC cannot be used to configure developer machines. And I am not even talking about shortage of out of the box and tested DSC resources like:

- Installing Visual Studio
- Installing Visual Studio Extensions
- Configuring Visual Studio Source Control to use TFS
- Configuring TFS workspaces

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest having a look at [Azure DevTest Labs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-lab/devtest-lab-developer-lab) for this kind of scenario of provisioning and customising developer machines.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Did not know about it. Unfortunately, it does not seem to help configure the on-premises dev machines.